# Ler Uma Tag que fica dentro de outra em um arquivo .xml com DOM API

Tags: java, xml, dom

Pegar dados de uma tag e logo após pegar dados de uma tag filha.
Por exemplo, tenho 2 tags que se repetem pelo documento inteiro, e eu preciso pegar dados das duas:

```
<teste:dadosLote>
<teste:numeroLote>380</unimed:numeroLote>
    <teste:dadosGuia>
       <teste:nomeBeneficiario>DIEGO AUGUSTO</teste:nomeBeneficiario>
    </teste:dadosGuia>

    <teste:dadosGuia>
       <teste:nomeBeneficiario>BRUNO HENRIQUE</teste:nomeBeneficiario>
    </teste:dadosGuia>
</teste:dadosLote>

<teste:dadosLote>
  <teste:numeroLote>381</unimed:numeroLote>
    <teste:dadosGuia>
       <teste:nomeBeneficiario>CARLOS</teste:nomeBeneficiario>
    </teste:dadosGuia>

    <teste:dadosGuia>
       <teste:nomeBeneficiario>FERNANDO</teste:nomeBeneficiario>
    </teste:dadosGuia>
</teste:dadosLote>
```

Eu consigo ler apenas uma Node por vez usando: `NodeList listaContatos = raiz.getElementsByTagName("teste:dadosGuia");`.
E depois que pego esse Node eu leio as tags que ficam dentro dele da seguinte forma: `contato.setNomeBeneficiario(obterValorElemento(elemento, "teste:nomeBeneficiario"));`
Como eu faço para ler o Node `<teste:dadosLote>` e pegar o seus valores também?

-------Código que le o arquivo xml-------

```
public List<UnimedLote> realizaLeituraXML(String arquivoXML) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    //fazer o parse do arquivo e criar o documento XML
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(arquivoXML);

    //Passo 1: obter o elemento raiz
    Element raiz = doc.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println("O elemento raiz é: " + raiz.getNodeName());

    //Passo 2: localizar os elementos filhos da agenda
    NodeList listaContatos = raiz.getElementsByTagName("teste:dadosLote");

    List<UnimedLote> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    //Passo 3: obter os elementos de cada elemento contato
    for (int i = 0; i < listaContatos.getLength(); i++) {
        NodeList dadosLoteChildrenNodeList = listaContatos.item(i).getChildNodes();
        //como cada elemento do NodeList é um nó, precisamos fazer o cast
        Element elementoContato = (Element) listaContatos.item(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < dadosLoteChildrenNodeList.getLength(); j++) {
            UnimedLote x = new UnimedLote();
            Node node = dadosLoteChildrenNodeList.item(j); // cuidado para nao usar o indice 'i'

            if (node == null || node.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                continue; // va para o proximo passo
            }

            System.out.println("o nome do no eh: '" + node.getNodeName() + "'");
            System.out.println("o conteudo do no eh: '" + node.getTextContent() + "'");

            System.out.println("");

        }

        //cria um objeto Contato com as informações do elemento contato
        UnimedLote contato = criaContato(elementoContato);

        lista.add(contato);

    }

    return lista;
}

public String obterValorElemento(Element elemento, String nomeElemento) {
    //obtém a lista de elementos
    NodeList listaElemento = elemento.getElementsByTagName(nomeElemento);
    if (listaElemento == null) {
        return null;
    }
    //obtém o elemento
    Element noElemento = (Element) listaElemento.item(0);
    if (noElemento == null) {
        return null;
    }
    //obtém o nó com a informação
    Node no = noElemento.getFirstChild();
    return no.getNodeValue();
}

public UnimedLote criaContato(Element elemento) {
    UnimedLote contato = new UnimedLote();


    /* Informaçoes do Beneficiário */
    contato.setNumeroDoLote(obterValorElemento(elemento, "teste:numeroLote"));
    contato.setNome(obterValorElemento(elemento, "teste:nomeBeneficiario"));
    return contato;
}

}
```

Trecho do xml:

```
<teste:dadosLote>
          <teste:seqLote>2</teste:seqLote>
          <teste:numeroLote>392</teste:numeroLote>
          <teste:dataEnvioLote>2015-04-01</teste:dataEnvioLote>
          <teste:numeroProtocolo>392</teste:numeroProtocolo>
          <teste:valorProtocolo>3976.17</teste:valorProtocolo>
          <teste:guia>
            <teste:dadosGuia>
              <teste:seqLote>2</teste:seqLote>
              <teste:seqGuia>1</teste:seqGuia>
              <teste:numeroGuiaPrestador>4444441</teste:numeroGuiaPrestador>
              <teste:beneficiario>
                <teste:numeroCarteira>9142132133</teste:numeroCarteira>
                <teste:nomeBeneficiario>DEBORA D P DOS SANTOS</teste:nomeBeneficiario>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu xml tem um problema o elemento `<teste:numeroLote>` é fechado com a tag `<unimed:numeroLote>`. Acho que isso foi problema de copiar e colar, correto?

Indo a sua pergunta, para você pegar os elementos filhos de um `Node` você utiliza o método [Node#getChildNodes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes()). No seu caso, para pegar o nó `<teste:dadosLote>` você pode executar as seguintes chamadas:

```
    // ...

    NodeList dadosLoteNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("teste:dadosLote");

    for (int i = 0; i < dadosLoteNodeList.getLength(); i++) {

        NodeList dadosLoteChildrenNodeList = dadosLoteNodeList.item(i).getChildNodes();

        int numeroDoLote = -1;
        List<String> nomeDosBeneficiarios = new LinkedList<String>();

        for (int j = 0; j < dadosLoteChildrenNodeList.getLength(); j++) {

            Node node = dadosLoteChildrenNodeList.item(j); // cuidado para nao usar o indice 'i'

            if (node.getNodeName().equals("teste:numeroLote")) {
                numeroDoLote = Integer.parseInt(node.getTextContent());
            } else if (node.getNodeName().equals("teste:dadosGuia")) {

                Node childNode = node.getFirstChild();

                while (childNode.getNextSibling() != null) {
                    childNode = childNode.getNextSibling();

                    if (childNode.getNodeName().equals("teste:nomeBeneficiario")) {
                        nomeDosBeneficiarios.add(node.getTextContent());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("lote#" + numeroDoLote);
        System.out.println("beneficiarios: " + nomeDosBeneficiarios);
    }
```

É recomendável, ao iterar sobre os nós filhos, checar se o filho também é um nó do tipo elemento, ou seja, que ele não seja um texto - nós que retornam `#text` na chamada [Node#getNomeName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeName()). Para fazer essa verificação faça:

```
    // ...

    Node node = dadosLoteChildrenNodeList.item(j);

    if (node == null || node.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        continue; // va para o proximo passo
    }

    // ..
```

Para maiores informações cheque os javadoc da oracle. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Editei com um trecho do xml, só nao fexei as tags pois tem muito conteúdo pra baixo ainda.

Comment: Eu acho que nao esta no mesmo nivel, pois ele não entra no else if que procura por <teste:dadosGuia>